# Custom Amazon EC2 instance and managing MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

so I've made an instance at amazon free web service, I've installed through putty mysql, php5, apache and so on on an ubuntu instance... But I can't for the life of me seem to find out how to manage the mysql on that instance. What am I missing? If I look in the Amazon RDS I can only manage for another instance, not for the one I have custom running...

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed MySQL in the EC2 instance you can manage it via terminal.

Login to your instance using putty/ssh and connect to MySQL using below command

```
mysql --user=username --password=password
```

you need to install MySQL client if you installed on only MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

> If I look in the Amazon RDS I can only manage for another instance, not for the one I have custom running...

Yes, RDS is a service where Amazon manages the entire database box for you. The AWS Console manages (paid) RDS instances, not databases in general.

> But I can't for the life of me seem to find out how to manage the mysql on that instance.

The "normal" way. Amazon doesn't come with CPanel or other GUI administration tools. Mainly because experts don't need them.

If you want to manage your MySQL graphically, install something like PHPMySQLAdmin or [the like](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3880961/Top-10-MySQL-GUI-Tools.htm).

Note: never open the MySQL port to the internet. If you need to connect to MySQL, use "port forwarding" in Putty to forward port 3306 to the remote box port 3306. Then you can run a MySQL GUI client locally.

Comment: Can I make a PHP gateway on Amazon RDS ? To mySQL db

Comment: Yes, but in that case, you wouldn't be using your own MySQL, you would be using RDS MySQL. Note that RDS does *not* give you a GUI to MySQL. RDS provides upgrades, backups, and failover so you don't have to.